# Old deleted answers reading

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Is there a shortcut to find my old deleted answers? 
I see a button for recent deleted answers but without possibility to extend the research.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105835

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for `deleted:true`, which will return all your deleted posts.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3Atrue

Comment: to be a Hacker is good!